# PHP - UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am using Cbeyond (www.cbeyond.com, some of you might be familiar with them) as a PHP Enabled webhost, I'm having issues with my PHP Upload functions, when I check as follows:

```
$error = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']; 
echo $error;
```

I get "6", for the error message: "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR"

I have a /tmp directory at my root, here is the file structure:

```
/ <--- ftp root (contains a working /tmp)
/www/htdocs/ <-- webroot
```

I've tried creating:

```
/www/htdocs/tmp (no luck)
```

Is there anyway to create a tmp location on the fly, I just need to parse an uploaded .txt file into my MySQL DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to check with CBeyond whether they allow file uploading or not. If so, check with them whether their php.ini File Uploads section has `upload_tmp_dir` properly defined.

Comment: thanks! I will do this. They have been pretty difficult so far so hopefully they do (kind of a dumb thing for them to leave out!)

I will report for reference!

Comment: Ok, CBeyond posted an 'editable' copy of the php.ini file for me, now I have been able to edit it, and set an upload directory (the shared one they use had.../usr/local/tmp) Anyways, I define my php.ini file to: /www/htdocs/tmp and run phpinfo.php and it correctly reflects this change, but my error persists! Doesn't the server have to reboot in some way?