# Cannot upload file in IE11 using PHP (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR)

Tags: php, file-upload, server

I'm getting an error with IE11 when trying to upload a file to my server.

The pertinent part of the upload form:

```
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST"><br>';
echo '<input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="displayName"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br></form>';
```

This works fine with Chrome, but IE gives me a `$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['error']` with value of:

> 6 (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR); Missing a temporary folder.

Another [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811929/php-upload-err-no-tmp-dir) for this error involved setting permissions with the OP's hosting company, but I am uploading to my own server. [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877763/cant-create-temporary-file-in-php-despite-the-temp-directory-exists) [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665255/define-a-temporary-dir-under-www-to-upload-files) in the sidebar do not seem pertinent.

I do not have a default temp directory set in php.ini. `sys_get_temp_dir()` returns C:\Windows\TEMP. Any reason why Chrome has no problem uploading to the temporary folder and IE thinks it's missing? Is there somewhere where I have to set a separate set of permissions for IE?

Thanks!

Comment: This should not depend on which browser is used – after all, it is just a server-side issue where the files are stored temporarily. Have you tried specifying an [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) in your configuration?

Comment: I set `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp` (/tmp has write privileges for users) but for some reason still get `sys_get_temp_dir() = C:\Windows\TEMP`. Looking into that now. 

I didn't think it would depend on the browser, but is there an explanation for why this works with Chrome? Are there any differences in how the php is handled or how the temporary directory is pointed to?

Comment: No, there should be no differences. And please use an absolute path for setting `upload_tmp_dir`.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe. Changed it to `upload_tmp_dir = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tmp"`  Still shows `sys_get_temp_dir()` as `C:\Windows\TEMP`, which I am assuming is the default temporary directory.  Shows the same thing in Chrome, but the file uploads without a problem.

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to check what value is actually used for `upload_tmp_dir`.

Comment: There were two `upload_tmp_dir` entires in `php.ini`, so I commented out the 2nd, which was set to `C:\Windows\TEMP` ... doh. Found that suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733183/unable-to-set-upload-tmp-dir-on-iis). `sys_get_temp_dir()` still shows `C:\Windows\TEMP` but `phpinfo()` shows the correct directory. Still no dice with IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried uploading with IE9 and it worked. The problem is with the default security settings that our institution's IE11 is installed with. So, this (of course) was NOT a browser issue. **Suspecting this, I should've gone straight to the settings when everything was working perfectly in Chrome.**

**CBroe**, thanks for the help (sorry to waste your time!)

Something secondary: My `php.ini` had 2 `upload_tmp_dir` lines, so commenting the latter (which pointed to `C:\Windows\Temp`) pointed it to the right directory.

Hopefully this saves someone some headache in the future.